# pyshark.tshark.tshark.TSharkNotFoundException: TShark not found

Tags: python, wireshark, tshark, pyshark

I am trying to run below code using pyshark on **MACOX Catlina** , when I run it I get the below exception (Also I ran below program using sudo ,incase if it was issue due to permission,but gives me same error)

```
    "Searched these paths: {}".format(possible_paths)
pyshark.tshark.tshark.TSharkNotFoundException: TShark not found. Try adding its location to the configuration file. Searched these paths: ['C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\dumpcap.exe', '/usr/local/bin/dumpcap', '/usr/bin/dumpcap', '/bin/dumpcap', '/usr/sbin/dumpcap', '/sbin/dumpcap', '/opt/X11/bin/dumpcap']
```

```
import pyshark

class SniffPacket(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.sniff()
    
    
    def sniff(self):
        capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='en0')
        capture.sniff(timeout=10)
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = SniffPacket()
```

I already have wireshark installed . Any help is appreciated . Is it because pyshark doesn't work on Mac ?

Comment: Well, the error says, "TShark not found."  Where is `tshark` installed on your system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open config.ini file and change the tshark path to the path where your tshark.exe is located. (Worked for Windows)
If this doesn't work try changing the dumpcap path also to the location where dumpcap.exe is stored.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue [Windows 11]. For me it was Wireshark not being installed along ***with the associated Tshark requirements/files***. After doing the wireshark install with the associate thsark files [it was an option in the installed exe) everything snapped into place.

Get the latest Wirehsark install =
https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Help with TShark =
https://tshark.dev/setup/install/